# How can i combine two Pandas dataframes while keeping columns of both in the new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this case, I want to combine `revenue_df` and `total_df`.

```py
revenue_df : https://i.stack.imgur.com/652KT.png <br>
total_df: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44j6A.png
```

I managed to do so using `.merge()` as shown:

[image: Combined dataframe]

However, the new merged dataframe only has columns from `revenue_df` and not from `total_df`. This prevents me from referencing `total_df's` columns in the merged dataframe.

`revenue_df.info()` shows this:

[image]

Is there a way I can merge both dataframes and get the columns of both dataframe in the merged one?

Comment: Try using `join` instead.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. But remember that pandas dataframes are immutable i.e the result of the merge will be a new dataframe.


You need to do `revenue_df = revenue_df.merge(total_df, on="Year", how="outer")` for the `revenue_df` dataframe to have the merged data

Comment: Merged dataframe is a new dataframe object so you will have to assign it back to a new label or reuse an old one. If you don't do the assignment, the created df object is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

`revenue_df.alias('df1').join(total_df.alias('df2'),on = df1['Year'] == df2['Year'],how = 'outer').select('df1.*','df2.*')`

Using join we can select all columns from both dataframes.
Also we can restrict which column to be fetched.